# Outsourcing colors into separate place in swift?

Tags: android, swift, colors, singleton, swift2

I'm using a lot of colors in my project and I wonder if there's a neat solution to outsource these colors into a class, singleton or whatever in order to keep things clean.

In Android Studio for example you have the possibility to create extra classes for strings, colors etc., which is pretty nice.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One common way is to use Swift Extensions. For example,

```
extension UIColor {

    class func myGreenColor() -> UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: 10/255, green: 152/255, blue: 66/255, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```

Comment: And is it possible put this extension into another class ?

Comment: Yes, from another class, you would just use `UIColor.myGreenColor()`.

Comment: No, I mean is it possible to declare the extension into another class than the one I want to use the color in ?

Comment: The extension can be declared in any file in your project.  Swift does not relate class (or struct, etc.) declarations to the name of the file nor restrict them to one per file.
Also, the extension is declared outside of any other class but can be used by any other class in the project.

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you very much :D

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear what you mean by "a lot of colors in my project" but one solution might be to create a file in your project called `MyColours.swift` and, in that file, to extend UIColor with all your custom colours.

```
import UIKit

extension UIColor {

    static func niceRed() -> UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 0.25, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
    }

    static func springBlue() -> UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: 0.7, green: 0.8, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
    }
```

}

Usage:

```
let background = UIColor.springBlue()
```